# Get only checked element from getElementsByName() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyname

I have a HTML like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="choice_shrd_with_me" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.file_name }}" />
```

I am trying to get only the checked elements in array like this in Javascript:

```
var choices = [];
         for (var i=0;i<document.getElementsByName('choice_shrd_with_me').length;i++){
             choices.push(document.getElementsByName("choice_shrd_with_me")[i].value);
         }
```

The above gets all the values whether the checkbox is checked or not. I want to get only the values on which checkbox is checked. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just filter for the elements which are checked:

```
var choices = [];
var els = document.getElementsByName('choice_shrd_with_me');
for (var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
  if ( els[i].checked ) {
    choices.push(els[i].value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just FIY, when working with `NodeList`s , it makes sense to cache the length. Because the list gets reevaluated (since it is live) whenever you access `.length`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sirko. I will accept your answer whenever I can.

Answer (score 4):

**For IE < 9**

```
function getCheckedByName(name){
    var chks = document.getElementsByName(name);
    var results = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++){
        chks[i].checked ? results.push(chks[i]):"";
    }
    return results;
}
```

**For Modern Browsers**

```
function getModernCheckedByName(name){
    return  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByName(name)).filter(function(e){
        return e.checked;
    });
}
```

**Working Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/yMqMf/

Answer (score 3):

For a vanilla js solution that doesn't require a loop use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
const choices = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='choice_shard_with_me']:checked")
```

Answer (score 1):

The JQuery version of it is quite slick:

```
var choices = [];
$("input[name='choice_shard_with_me']:checked").each(function() {
    choices.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

[:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) (with quite similar example of what you want to accomplish)

[each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

[attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks the solution is perfect for **checkbox**

but in any case if decided to change checkbox with **radiobox**

Simply can get the selected value of radiobox like the following :

```
var varName = $('input[name="formItemName"]:checked').val();  // To get selected item of your radiobox
```